# Bert model for text classification using tensorflow and transformers

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, bert-language-model

i create top layer with bert to generate embedding but I'm getting error

**Bert model**

these is the pretrained model imports from transformers

```
from transformers import BertTokenizerFast, BertForMaskedLM, TFBertModel
Model_name = 'bert-base-cased'
# bert_model = BertForMaskedLM.from_pretrained("bert-base-multilingual-cased")
tokeniser = BertTokenizerFast.from_pretrained(Model_name)
bert_encoder = TFBertModel.from_pretrained(Model_name)
```

**model**

model with bert layer dropout and output layers

```
text_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(), dtype=tf.string, name='text')
preprocessed_text = tokeniser(text_input,padding=True,truncation=True,return_tensors='tf')
outputs = bert_encoder(text_input)
polled_output = outputs.poller_output
# Neural network layers
l = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.1, name="dropout")(polled_output)
l = tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='sigmoid', name="output")(l)

# Use inputs and outputs to construct a final model
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=[text_input], outputs = [l])
```

at preprocessing im getting the error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[104], line 2
      1 text_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(), dtype=tf.string, name='text')
----> 2 preprocessed_text = tokeniser(text_input,padding=True,truncation=True,return_tensors='tf')
      3 outputs = bert_encoder(text_input)
      4 polled_output = outputs.poller_output

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\transformers\tokenization_utils_base.py:2520, in PreTrainedTokenizerBase.__call__(self, text, text_pair, text_target, text_pair_target, add_special_tokens, padding, truncation, max_length, stride, is_split_into_words, pad_to_multiple_of, return_tensors, return_token_type_ids, return_attention_mask, return_overflowing_tokens, return_special_tokens_mask, return_offsets_mapping, return_length, verbose, **kwargs)
   2518     if not self._in_target_context_manager:
   2519         self._switch_to_input_mode()
-> 2520     encodings = self._call_one(text=text, text_pair=text_pair, **all_kwargs)
   2521 if text_target is not None:
   2522     self._switch_to_target_mode()

File ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python310\site-packages\transformers\tokenization_utils_base.py:2578, in PreTrainedTokenizerBase._call_one(self, text, text_pair, add_special_tokens, padding, truncation, max_length, stride, is_split_into_words, pad_to_multiple_of, return_tensors, return_token_type_ids, return_attention_mask, return_overflowing_tokens, return_special_tokens_mask, return_offsets_mapping, return_length, verbose, **kwargs)
   2575         return False
   2577 if not _is_valid_text_input(text):
-> 2578     raise ValueError(
   2579         "text input must of type `str` (single example), `List[str]` (batch or single pretokenized example) "
   2580         "or `List[List[str]]` (batch of pretokenized examples)."
   2581     )
   2583 if text_pair is not None and not _is_valid_text_input(text_pair):
   2584     raise ValueError(
   2585         "text input must of type `str` (single example), `List[str]` (batch or single pretokenized example) "
   2586         "or `List[List[str]]` (batch of pretokenized examples)."
   2587     )

ValueError: text input must of type `str` (single example), `List[str]` (batch or single pretokenized example) or `List[List[str]]` (batch of pretokenized examples).
```